# can I use geofencing in a fremium account, i'm having issues uploading a geofence to the server

Tags: here-api

I created a free account with here technologies as I need to create geofences around traffic signals and check if any of my devices entered the geofences and trigger a action.

```
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'apikeyhere' // here i used the javascript maps api key
    });

    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    var lineString = new H.geo.LineString()
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 15.376727, lng: 73.925272 })
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 15.376747, lng: 73.925926 })
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 15.377875, lng: 73.926001 })
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 15.377916, lng: 73.925357 })
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 15.376727, lng: 73.925272 })

    var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: { lng: 73.925658, lat: 15.376116 }
        });
    var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);
    var north = new H.map.Polygon(lineString)
    var northgeo = north.getGeometry()
    var northWKT = northgeo.toString()
    console.log(northWKT)
    map.addObject(north)
    var zip = new JSZip()
    zip.file("data.wkt", "NAME\tWKT\n" + "NorthFence\t" + northWKT)
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(content => {
        saveAs(content, "hello.zip");
        var formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append("zipfile", content)
        axios.post("https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/layers/upload.json", formdata,
            {
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
                parms: {
                    "layer_id": "15537",
                    "apikey": "apikeyhere"//here i use the rest api key of my freemium account
                }
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("ERROR")
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
    })
```

but I'm getting the error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with a free account, it's not clear if it is. The video tutorial I'm following is out of date as there was a switch to using a API key instead of APP ID along with the API code.
To upload the WKT zip file via post request, I'm using the HERE Location Services REST APIs key and to draw the map I'm using HERE Maps API for JavaScript key

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create Geofence using freemium account. Here is the code with JS 3.1 you can try-

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
    <body style="margin: 0">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stuk.github.io/jszip/dist/jszip.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="heremap.js"></script>
        <script>
           
        const start = async () => {
    const map = new HereMap("Your JS API KEY", document.getElementById("map"));
    const lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 37, lng: -121 });
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 37.2, lng: -121.002 });
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 37.2, lng: -121.2 });
    lineString.pushPoint({ lat: 37, lng: -121 });
    const polygon = new H.map.Polygon(lineString);
    console.log(map.polygonToWKT(polygon));
    map.draw(polygon);
    const geofenceResponse = await map.uploadGeofence("1234", "Demo Layer", map.polygonToWKT(polygon));
};
start();
    </script>
</body>
```

Heremap.js

```
class HereMap {

constructor(apikey, mapElement) {
  //this.appId = appId;
      //this.appCode = appCode;
      this.apikey = apikey;
      this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
          'apikey': 'Your JS API Key'
      });
      this.map = new H.Map(
          mapElement,
          this.platform.createDefaultLayers().vector.normal.map,
          {
              zoom: 10,
              center: { lat: 37, lng: -121 }
          }
      );
      const mapEvent = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map);
      const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvent);
      this.geofencing = this.platform.getGeofencingService();
      this.currentPosition = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 37.21, lng: -121.21 });
      this.map.addObject(this.currentPosition);
      this.map.addEventListener("tap", (ev) => {
var target = ev.target;
this.map.removeObject(this.currentPosition);
this.currentPosition = new H.map.Marker(this.map.screenToGeo(ev.currentPointer.viewportX, ev.currentPointer.viewportY));
this.map.addObject(this.currentPosition);
this.fenceRequest(["1234"], this.currentPosition.getGeometry()).then(result => 
  {
    if(result.geometries.length > 0) {
        alert("You are in Geofence area")
    } else {
        console.log("you are out");
    }
});
  }, false);

}
draw(mapObject) {
 this.map.addObject(mapObject);
 }
polygonToWKT(polygon) {
  const geometry = polygon.getGeometry();
      return geometry.toString();
}
uploadGeofence(layerId, name, geometry) {

  const zip = new JSZip();
      zip.file("data.wkt", "NAME\tWKT\n" + name + "\t" + geometry);
      return zip.generateAsync({ type:"blob" }).then(content => {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("zipfile", content);
          return axios.post("https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/layers/upload.json", formData, {
              headers: {
                  "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
              },
              params: {
                  "apikey": 'Your JS API Key',
              
                  "layer_id": layerId
              }
          });
      });
}
fenceRequest(layerIds, position) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.geofencing.request(
              H.service.extension.geofencing.Service.EntryPoint.SEARCH_PROXIMITY,
              {
                "apikey": 'Your JS API KEY',
               
                  'layer_ids': layerIds,
                  'proximity': position.lat + "," + position.lng,
                  'key_attributes': ['NAME']
              },
              result => {
                  resolve(result);
              }, error => {
                  reject(error);
              }
          );
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: can you help understand why the my code is not working? the part where I upload the fence is exactly the same as yours. thanks, your code works