# Which credentials and tooling do I use to authenticate to the HERE geofencing/fleet APIs?

Tags: authentication, authorization, here-api

I have been trying to apply some geofencing to my Here map, but continually get 401 and 403 responses from the geofencing endpoints no matter what I do.

I was originally using the node module '@here/maps-api-for-javascript' but I saw indicators that it was not possible to do geofencing with that tool, and so I have switched to pulling down scripts (v3.1) from CDN and making direct REST calls to fill in any gaps as outlined in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821365/can-i-use-geofencing-in-a-fremium-account-im-having-issues-uploading-a-geofenc), I have created a test project using the exact code provided at that SO post with my api key, and the map does not render at all, let alone the geofencing (but the triangle and marker are rendered). In the console I see 403s for all calls to the APIs.

I have tried:

- JS API key from developer account
- REST API key from developer account
- platform API key from platform account
- oauth API token from platform account
- app_id and app_code params with my JS app id and JS API key
- app_id and app_code params with my REST app id and REST app key

My keys work to render my map, calculate routes, and update routehandles in my app, so I'm not sure why they are not working for these two calls - one to upload the fences, and one to check position against them.

Additionally in my app I had tried to do geofencing as outlined in [this tutorial from here](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/gfe_upload_created_route_fence) but when I try to access the platform.ext.getGeoFencingService (line 163 in view source at that link) I get an error that platform.ext is undefined.

Adding to my confusion, one part of the docs says that apikeys are read only, and another part of the docs says that starting with JS api v3.1 that you no longer need app_id and app_code.

Comment: I copied the same code and tried with my free account JS API Key and it works as expected. Could you please check the projects page for your js api key and create a new api key (if old one not working) and try again?

Comment: You can also share your app id with us to check if it is in valid state.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get  everything working as needed :) Unfortunately I couldn't get the key to work for geofencing no matter what I did (including new keys :() BUT it turned out that I didn't really need to hit the HERE systems for our geofencing since our fences were static and we were able to just check them locally using a lib.